# Good resources for learning Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have developed for a number of years in Java, primarily for Linux and Windows.  During my undergrad and grad school times, I also did quite a bit in C and C++.  I have recently (in the last year and a half) started using primarily Apple computers at home, and am interested in exploring their Xcode development environment.  I am interested in learning how to use the Cocoa interface, etc.  However, I know nothing (or next to nothing) about Objective-C.  I am aware it is a pure superset of C, however I am interested in some resources for learning it.

In the past, to teach myself concepts of Swing for Java, I have used O'Reilly books, such as the Swing Bible, Java Swing by Marc Loy et. al. Is there a similar book for Objective-C, or a book that is really good to learn from?  I would prefer if it was fairly technical, had examples, etc.  Has anyone else attempted to learn Objective-C this way?  Are there any specific things I should look at?

Just to note, yes I do have K&R, I have read it too many times to count, and I am aware of C syntax.  It has been a while, but I do remember large amounts of it.  :)  I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535198/best-way-to-learn-objective-c), but I did not see any particular resources mentioned, simply some general statements about learning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Cocoa Core Compentencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Accessibility.html) - Apple's official basic documentation for the language and the Cocoa framework.
- [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134076958) - The definitive book for Cocoa newcomers. It's actually focused on the Cocoa frameworks more than Objective-C, but still invaluable.
- [Programming in Objective-C 2.0](http://www.informit.com/store/programming-in-objective-c-9780321967602) - Focuses on Objective-C itself more than Cocoa; may have more basic information than an experienced programmer would need, but covers plenty of good stuff.
- The ["Language" part](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/pt01.html) of [Matt Neuberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) *Programming iOS 6* covers Objective-C itself in detail.
- [CocoaDevCentral](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/) - **Excellent** tutorials. Start with the "Learn ..." and "Objective-C Style" tutorials.
- Stanford's free [CS193E](http://cs193e.stanford.edu/) and [CS193P](http://cs193p.stanford.edu/) courses
- [CocoaHeads.org](http://cocoaheads.org/) - A large list of resources (books, website, and code) about Cocoa/Objective-C.
- HyperJeff's [Cocoa Literature List](http://osx.hyperjeff.net/Reference/CocoaArticles) - A huge compendium of useful information, etc.
- [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/) - An excellent blog with specific, useful snippets and in-depth explanation.
- [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/) - A fun and useful blog (usually) about Cocoa.
- [Best Practices for Cocoa Programmers](http://conferences.oreillynet.com/cs/macosx2004/view/e_sess/5828) (by Aaron Hillegass) - A bit dated, but contains some nuggets and guidelines for understanding and following Objective-C/Cocoa conventions
- [CocoaDev.com wiki](http://cocoadev.com/) - Especially good for specific questions about a specific class or task. (Undergoing updates.)