# Perform Action for x times in Objective-C (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS-Developement and my question is if it is possible to run some action a fix set number of times.
I want to perform an action for exactly 20 times.

Comment: If the answer to your question is really "[for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)" you might want to take a step back and start with a book or tutorial series that starts at the very beginning.

Comment: If you're just starting out, asking questions on Stack Overflow is not the place you need to be. You should find a good book or a series of online tutorials. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really know what you want but it seems you are looking for

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
     //do your action.
}
```

also if you want it to be performed in background and not on main queue 
you can use  [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)
or [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
and put `for` inside GCD or NSThread.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you're looking at a classic for loop in Objective -C. Here's how it goes

```
for (/* Instantiate local variables*/ ; /* Condition to keep looping. */ ; /* End of loop expressions */)
{
    // Do something.
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
}
```

If you wish to loop through objects in an Array its the same

```
for (NSString* currentString in myArrayOfStrings)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", currentString);
}
```

You can also use the while loop

```
while(number<= 20)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: for the `while` loop
don't you want to instantiate the `number` and add the `number++;` somewhere in the `while` so it won't be an endless loop ?