# Xcode: expression is not assignable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to "refresh"/"update" a shared string in my app after a user has successfully authenticated. Here's what I have:

```
// MyAuth.h
//@interface
+ (NSString *)sharedAuthToken;

// MyAuth.m
+ (NSString *)sharedAuthToken {
    static NSString *_sharedAuthToken = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedAuthToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];
    });

    return _sharedAuthToken;
}

// AuthCtrl.m
- (void)saveOauthInfo:(NSString *)token {

    [MyAuth sharedAuthToken] = token; // getting error here
}
```

I would like to update or refresh the `sharedAuthToken`. How can I do this?

*Let me know if the code is too confusing or too cluttered..

Comment: Do you want to just set the token in memory, or do you also want to store the new token in the user defaults?

Comment: @robmayoff Thx for the quick reply. I would like to set the token in memory

Comment: I don't want this to sound rude, but you're not going to do very well overall if you're piecing your app together by asking questions on Stack Overflow. You should find a good book or a series of online tutorials and really learn the tools you're using. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Good luck!

Comment: @JoshCaswell Don't worry, no offense taken. Thank you. Looks like a good read, will check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another class method:

```
+(void) setSharedAuthToken:(NSString *) token;
```

Move `_sharedAuthToken` from the `sharedAuthToken` method to *outside* the scope of the class but still *inside* the `MyAuth.m` file:

```
static NSString *_sharedAuthToken;

@implementation MyAuth ...
```

Implement the new class method:

```
+(void) setSharedAuthToken:(NSString *) token {
   _sharedAuthToken = token; 
}
```

Then in your `saveOauthInfo` method:

```
[MyAuth setSharedAuthToken:token];
```

Comment: you're using an ivar in a class method? this won't compile; I think the solution was to save it to user defaults

Comment: That's a really good point. You could add a `static NSString *_sharedAuthToken` outside of the scope of the class implementation but inside of the .m file.

Comment: I'd consider wrapping the assignment in the setter with `@synchronized(_sharedAuthToken) { ... }` if you go this route.

Answer (score 1):

You have no setter method.

`+ (NSString *)sharedAuthToken` is a "getter", only returning data.

You should setup a @property, if it suits your needs, which would generate a setter for you, or create your own.

e.g.

`+ (void)setSharedAuthToken:(NSString *)token { ... }`

Of course, since you made your getter store the token in a static local variable and furthermore wrapped its setting in a dispatch_once to make it a singleton, you'll have to refactor all that.

Comment: you cannot declare a property on the Class level, OP needs to make a singleton instance than has the property. is that what you meant by "refactor all that"?

Comment: That's exactly what I was alluding to.