# Is keychain data that I store restricted to my app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keychain

If I put some information into the keychain, my app is the only one who is able to have access to that data, correct?

Comment: One question per post, please. Your question about the syntax of ObjC indicates that you may want to find a good book or a series of online tutorials. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keychain data are shared across a developer's applications.
From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html):

> Keychain data for an app is stored outside of the app’s sandbox. When
>   the user backs up app data using iTunes, the keychain data is also
>   backed up. Before iOS 4.0, keychain data could only be restored to the
>   device from which the backup was made. In iOS 4.0 and later, a
>   keychain item that is password protected can be restored to a
>   different device only if its accessibility is not set to
>   kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly or any other value that
>   restricts it to the current device. Upgrading an app does not affect
>   that app’s keychain data.

[Here](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/) is an example of sharing keychain information between applications.

Answer (score 0):

The data an app puts into the Keychain is restricted to a single developer's apps. It can be shared by multiple apps by the same developer if desired or restricted to that app.

See WWDC13 2013 video "Protecting Secrets with the Keychain". You can access it either on you computer or on an iOS device with the Apple WWDC app.

Comment: I see, that makes me more relief. I will be sure to check out the video, thanks for your help :)