# Individual Class For Sprite

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, pass-data

I've been using objective-c and sprite kit for a while, but always used one enormous class for everything. For this app, I need to have multiple classes. How can I have a class, lets say named MySprite.m, which would have all the code for the sprite, and the be able to add the sprite or call methods inside MySprite.m in GameScene.m?

Comment: You should find a good book or a series of online tutorials. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to create and call methods in a new class:

1) Create a new class called `MySprite` with an `init` method

```
#import "MySprite.h"

@implementation MySprite

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Add initialization code here, as needed
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) addSprite {
    // Do something here

}

@end
```

2) In MySprite.h, declare methods and properties

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MySprite : NSObject

// Declare this if you want to add nodes to the scene in your SKScene subclass
@property (nonatomic, weak) SKScene *scene;

// Declare methods to be called externally
- (void) addSprite;

@end
```

3) In GameScene.m, allocate and initialize a `MySprite` instance

```
MySprite *mySprite = [[MySprite alloc] init];
mySprite.scene = self;

// Call a MySprite method
[mySprite addSprite];
```

Comment: Thanks! I must say that's probably the best answer I've ever gotten

Comment: I just have one problem. When I try to add the sprite inside addSprite method using [self addChild:sprite];, i get an error. I know that the error is because I'm using that function outside the GameScene.m file, but how can I get around this?

Comment: @TheCommonGiraffe use [self.scene addChild:sprite];