# Accessing textfield.text in an NSArray by index

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, nsarray

I have an array of text fields. I'm using a `for` loop to go through the array and check to see if the text field's text attribute is empty.

```
NSArray *arrayOfTextFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: _nameTextfield, _emailTextfield, _phoneTextfield, _termTextfield, _schoolTextfield, _graduationTextfield, _gpaTextfield, _degreeTextfield, _interestTextfield, _groupTextfield, _appliedTextfield, nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfLabels count]; i++) {

    if ([[arrayOfTextFields objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"if statement ran");
    }
}
```

Obviously the `if` statement does not run because it is comparing a text field to a string. I can't figure out how to do this syntactically in Objective-C. Something like this would be incredibly easy in C++ or Java, it might look something like `arrayOfTextFields[i].text == "";` That is essentially what I'm trying to do. I have struggled to find references to the sort of thing online.

Comment: If you're just starting out, asking questions on Stack Overflow is not the place you need to be. You should find a good book or a series of online tutorials. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reference, however, right now I do not have the time to scour a bunch of tutorials to look for an answer that may not be there. Even if you don't tell me how to do it, I would love some hints and pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayOfTextFields = [NSArray array];//set your labels here

    for (UITextField *textField in arrayOfTextFields) {

        if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSLog(@"if statement ran");
        }
    }
```

or you can try this also..

```
NSArray *arrayOfTextFields = [NSArray array];//set your labels here

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfTextFields count]; i++) {

        if ([((UITextField*)[arrayOfTextFields objectAtIndex:i]).text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSLog(@"if statement ran");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ your code solves the asker's problem.

Comment: I didn't think about doing the quick enumeration method. That appears like it would work. I'll try it out

Comment: @JoshCaswell  "I can't figure out how to do this syntactically in objective-c" .. I just wrote down how to  .. THE END

Answer (score 0):

The strings in the text fields are not the same as the text fields themselves. You must access the `text` property of the field in order to compare it to another string. The syntax is exactly the same as what you quoted for C++ or Java: `arrayOfTextFields[i].text`.

You can also use `[[arrayOfTextFields objectAtIndex:i] text]`. The two are completely equivalent in effect (there are some differences in implementation that aren't important here).

You should also typically use [fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW1) with `NSArray`s. Thus your loop can look like this:

```
for( UITextField * field in array ){
    if( [field.text isEqualToString:@""] ){
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```