# run a function on any change of UISegmented control?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Looking for something like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *modeSelect;

if(modeselect.valueChanged){}
```

Other answers I found confuse me as I don't get the square brackets notation. Please do not send me tutorials on understanding that until after main question has been answered.

Comment: If you don't understand the basic syntax of Objective-C then you really do need to learn that first. You can't write an app in a language if you don't understand the basic syntax of the language. Do yourself a favor and take time to find some good Objective-C tutorials before you do anything else. Otherwise you won't even understand any answers you get to your question.

Comment: Now that the main question is answered, you should have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an action to your segmented control.

You can do so in your storyboard directly (ctrl-drag from the segmented control to an empty space in your view controller, and select "value changed"). You'll get an `IBAction` method that will be called when the value changes.