# How to declare and define functions in objective-c like in c?

Tags: objective-c

My code looks like

```
- int add_two_numbers:(int)number1 secondnumber:(int)number2;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

- int add_two_numbers:(int)number1 secondnumber:(int)number2
{
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

I got error saying "missing context for method declaration" and "expected method body". I am following the tutorials on tutorialpoints on objective-c, but it is very vague in this [section](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_functions.htm). It seems like the methods have to be in some classes, and cannot go alone like what I did. What's going on?

Comment: That tutorial is doing an absolutely terrible job of teaching you about this. Functions exist in ObjC, distinctly from methods; they are related at a deeper level, but _not the same thing_. "Basically in Objective-C, we call the function as method" is nonsense. I would suggest finding another resource to learn from. Have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660)

Comment: you can directly call c's function from objective c.

Comment: You could make that a normal C function: `int add_two_numbers(int number1, int number2)`

Comment: That tutorial is just flat out wrong in a number of places.  I would recommend against using it for anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods like the second one can only live in classes.  You can use the C stand-alone syntax whenever you want a stand-alone function.

Also, your syntax is slightly off -- in a class, you'd declare it like this:

```
- (int)add_two_numbers:(int)number1 secondnumber:(int)number2
{
   return number1 + number2;
}
```

With the return type in parentheses.

Comment: Except you shouldn't use '_' and it should be camel cased.  I.e. `- (NSInteger) addNumberOne:(NSInteger)numberOne toSecondNumber:(NSInteger) numberTwo;` or the like.